# Giving examples and explaining

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Assuming, I have to comment on a topic (e.g. Refugees in the European Union) and I have prove an assumption by explaining and giving an example.

For example:
The EU has to accept the refugees **because of** humanity. **For example**, the people, who have traveled more than 500 km can't just be sent back home, **because** they would get killed in their home country.

1. Which are good expression for explanations and examples?
2. Is it possible to say:

   > This can be seen at the example of Mohammad Abdul ...

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, are you requesting phrases? Mark your examples with "Ex."

Comment: How do you mean this? Marking the examples? I tried typing ex in the text; but the program didn't mark the text as example.

Comment: @black: Type `* >` at the beginning of each separate example, then make sure the rest of that line is exactly the text of that example with nothing added or removed.

Comment: No, I mean literally, when you want to give an example as part of an assignment, you can write Ex. to say the thing that follows is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The EU is obliged to accept refugees for humanitarian reasons. People
>   who have travelled more than 500 miles cannot simply be sent home to be killed.
>   **Take, for example, the case of Mohammad Abdul...**

Does that help?